# how to answer "What is the total amount of money spent each month" for UK visa

Tags: visas, uk

I am working and the amount of money I spend each month varies widely. Do i include non recurrent expenses like money I spent for my husband's birthday gift, cake and dinner? hospital bill for a surgery? fees for registering a one-time exam?

I intend to sum up the recurrent(bills,subscriptions, groceries) and occasional expenses eg medications and use the average as my monthly expenses.

Is this the right thing?

Answer (score 1):

I believe a reasonable and professional visa official would only expect to see regular expenses listed in applications.

Be truthful in these and I would not expect you to have any issues whatsoever :)